# In the coq tactics language, what is the difference between intro and intros

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

In the Coq tactics language, what is the difference between

`intro`

and

`intros`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### `intro` and `intros` behave differently if no argument is supplied

According to the [reference manual](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.8.0/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.intro):

> If the goal is neither a product nor starting with a let definition, the tactic `intro` applies the tactic `hnf` until the tactic `intro` can be applied or the goal is not head-reducible.

On the other hand, `intros`, as a variant of `intro` tactic,

> repeats `intro` until it meets the head-constant. It never reduces head-constants and it never fails.

Example:

```
Goal not False.
  (* does nothing *)
  intros.
  (* unfolds `not`, revealing `False -> False`;
     moves the premise to the context *)      
  intro.
Abort.
```

Note: both `intro` and `intros` do the same thing if an argument is supplied (`intro contra` / `intros contra`).

#### `intros` is polyvariadic, `intro` can only take 0 or 1 arguments

```
Goal True -> True -> True.
  Fail intro t1 t2.
  intros t1 t2.  (* or `intros` if names do not matter *)
Abort.
```

#### `intro` does *not* support intro-patterns

```
Goal False -> False.
  Fail intro [].
  intros [].
Qed.
```

Some information about intro-patterns can be found in the [manual](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.8.0/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.intros) or in the [Software Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu) book. See also [this example](https://github.com/tchajed/coq-tricks/blob/master/IntroPatterns.v) of not-so-trivial combination of several intro-patterns.

#### `intros` does not support `after` / `before` / `at top` / `at bottom` switches

Let's say we have a proof state like this

```
H1 : True
H2 : True /\ True
H3 : True /\ True /\ True
==========
True /\ True /\ True /\ True -> True
```

then e.g. `intro H4 after H3` will modify the proof state like so:

```
H1 : True
H2 : True /\ True
H4 : True /\ True /\ True /\ True 
H3 : True /\ True /\ True
==========
True
```

and `intro H4 after H1` will produce

```
H4 : True /\ True /\ True /\ True 
H1 : True
H2 : True /\ True
H3 : True /\ True /\ True
==========
True
```

Comment: The manual is a bit incorrect in saying `intros` repeats `intro` - it never unfolds definitions, so `repeat intro` is different from `intros`. What it repeats is `intro` without the `hnf` step.

Comment: I think the manual says what you are saying in the second sentence: "It never reduces head-constants ..."

Comment: Yes, that does help clarify, but I still think `intros` doesn't repeat `intro` and the manual could emphasize this difference (I consider unexpected unfolding a big deal). This difference really surprised me when I ran into https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/5394.